# System.Reflection.Emit custom property seems to be identical to my mock up, but I get an InvalidProgramException

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

To expand on the title, I'm using Reflection to generate a custom subclass that will eventually have an arbitrary number of string properties which they'll internally store in a dictionary.  In this case I'm just using one.  I've used Ildasm.exe to get the MSIL that I need for the 
My Set method works, as the debugger shows the value I'm assigning, but when I try to read it back I get an InvalidProgramException, "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program." which points back to the get method.  My get method model is:

```
/* public class TestWrapper : AttributeWrapper  //This is the source of the following MSIL
            {
                public string Name
                {
                    get { return GetAttribute("Name"); }
                    set { SetAttribute("Name", value); }
                }
            }
*/
    {
      // Code size       17 (0x11)
      .maxstack  2
      .locals init ([0] string V_0)
      IL_0000:  nop
      IL_0001:  ldarg.0
      IL_0002:  ldstr      "Name"
      IL_0007:  call       instance string ConfigXMLParser.frmNodeBuilder/AttributeWrapper::GetAttribute(string)
      IL_000c:  stloc.0
      IL_000d:  br.s       IL_000f

      IL_000f:  ldloc.0
      IL_0010:  ret
    } // end of method TestWrapper::get_Name
```

And code generating the property in question is:

```
  public static void CreateSelfNamingProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
            MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr =
                tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName,
                    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                    typeof(string), Type.EmptyTypes);
            Type[] getAttributeArgs = { typeof(string) };
            Type basetype = tb.BaseType;
            MethodInfo getAttrBase = basetype.GetMethod("GetAttribute", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            Debug.Assert(getAttrBase != null);

            ILGenerator ilGen = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            Label labelReturn = ilGen.DefineLabel();
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);           //The Get function starts here.  
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Nope.");
            ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, getAttrBase, getAttributeArgs);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, labelReturn);
            ilGen.MarkLabel(labelReturn);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
                tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                    MethodAttributes.Public |
                    MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                    MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                    null, new[] { propertyType });

            MethodInfo setAttrBase
                = basetype.GetMethod("SetAttribute", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
            Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
            Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();
            Type[] setParamTypes = { typeof(string) , typeof(string) };

            setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop); //The Set method starts here
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyName);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
            setIl.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, setAttrBase, setParamTypes);


            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
            setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
            setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
            propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
        }


// And this is what builds the TypeBuilder:

        public static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
        {
            string typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
            AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature,
                    TypeAttributes.Public |
                    TypeAttributes.Class |
                    TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                    TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                    TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                    TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
                    null);
            return tb;
        }
```

Finally, putting it all together:

```
            TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder("TestType");
            CreateSelfNamingProperty(tb, "Name", typeof(string));
            dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(tb.CreateType());
            instance.Name = "Test"; //Debug shows Name is Test, but
            MessageBox.Show(instance.Name);//Exception occurs here
```

And the base class is pretty straightforward:

```
  public class AttributeWrapper
        {
            protected Dictionary<string, string> _attributes =
                new Dictionary<string, string>();

            protected void SetAttribute(string attribute, string value)
            {
                if (_attributes.ContainsKey(attribute))
                {
                    _attributes[attribute] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    _attributes.Add(attribute, value);
                }
            }

            protected string GetAttribute(string attribute)
            {
                return _attributes.ContainsKey(attribute) ? _attributes[attribute] : "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've got a method with locals but you don't declare any in your dynamic method. Where do you expect stloc and ldloc to read/write to?

Comment: Also, I recommend using sharplab to see the IL it's a lot easier than using ildasm back and forth. You may also want to use callvirt instead of call. Also the nops aren't really necessary...My guess is your original was compiled as a debug build.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks!  I added a DeclareLocal(typeof(string)) and that fixed it.  I kind of figured the nops weren't necessary, but I wanted to try to match the source I had exactly.   Had no idea about the type array- I'll strip that out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you are using the `stloc.0` and `ldloc.0` opcodes to read/write into a local without having defined any locals! You can fix that by calling the following at the top of your method:

`ilGen.DeclareLocal(typeof(string));`

Now here's the thing, the local isn't  really required. The code you disassembled and used as your template was obviously compiled in `Debug` mode. I can tell this due to the local but mostly from the `nop`'s. These two things exist in the debug build to aide in the debugging process, allowing you to step in and view the intermediate values. Your getter can be reduced to the following IL:

```
ldarg.0
ldstr "Nope."
call instance string [AttributeWrapper]::GetAttribute(string)
ret
```

Similarly, your setter can have its `nop`'s removed.

Some other side notes:

You are using the wrong method to emit your `call` instruction. The `EmitCall` method [is for calling `varargs` methods only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.emitcall?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) and accepts an argument containing the types of the `varargs` parameters. That's not what you have here. That either involves some p/invoke against an API using the `VarCall` convention and/or `TypedReference`/`__makeref` and `__arglist`/`ArgIterator`. The latter of which are "hidden" C# keywords that you will almost never find in code. Way back in the days prior to .NET 2.0 the method threw an exception when the target `MethodInfo` wasn't `varargs` but this is not the case anymore.

You should instead use the normal `Emit` method and pass the appropriate `Call` or `CallVirt`* `OpCode`.

Finally, I'd strongly suggest using [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/) for this purpose, specifically setting it to `Release` build and viewing the IL tab. It's a *whole lot* easier than compiling the code and then disassembling manually.

* Often you will see people use the latter, even when the method isn't `virtual`.